# Is there a way to encode an array Independent of its rotation?

Tags: arrays, data-structures

I have an array of numbers, repititions are allowed. I can rotate the array by popping of the end and putting it back in the front, or popping from the front and putting it on the end, so that I can rotate it both ways. I'm doing this to model a looping structure, but I want a way to encode or represent an array in such a way that it is equal to its different rotated versions when encoded.
For example:

```
a = [1, 3, 2, 3]
rotatedA = [3, 2, 3, 1]
```

I want a way to encode an array such that
`encoded(a) == encoded(rotatedA)`.
The example shows only 1 rotation of the array a, but this should be true with any rotation. All possible rotations of an array should be equal when encoded.

The encoding doesn't have to be anything special. It could be something that just rotates the array to a specific point, such that it brings all rotated versions to the same place. This would be like selecting the same exact place to rotate to, regardless of starting rotation, then rotating to it.
For example:

```
a1 = [1, 2, 3] 
a2 = [2, 3, 1] 
a3 = [3, 1, 2]  
encoded(a1) == [2, 3, 1]  (encoded selects index 1, rotates to it)  
encoded(a2) == [2, 3, 1]  (encoded selects index 0, rotates to it)  
encoded(a3) == [2, 3, 1]  (encoded selects index 2, rotates to it)
```

But, I have found no way of doing that.
Also, the encoding needs to make sure different arrays that are not rotations of each other are different. So if arrays a and b are not rotations of each other, `encoded(a)` must not be equal to `encoded(b)`.

I've tried to search for a solution online for a while now, and I don't see any mention of this kind of problem. I don't know if it has a known solution and I just don't know the name of the problem.

Some special data structure could probably fit it, but I couldn't see anything that was actually worked, nor a proof that such a encoding (or structure) was impossible. This problem is just a way of storing circular objects, and I feel that would have been made before. I've thought of linked lists with their ends connected, but that still doesn't fit, as you must have an entrance somewhere. You would still need a way to put the entrance in the same place across all rotations, and that goes back to one of my examples.

I tried to think of a way of exploiting the structure, like finding the distances between the maxes of the array, but I only found a way for arrays of length 7.

Comment: Use a heuristic like finding the smallest unique element and rotating to that. In the absence of a unique element, rotate to the smallest unique difference between consecutive elements or something like that.

Comment: Your question is a little vague on the requirements for this encoding. One encoding could be the sorted array and the permutation number. You can generate the nth permutation of a sorted array. Eric Lippert covers how to do that in his series on permutations. The first part of the series is at https://ericlippert.com/2013/04/15/producing-permutations-part-one/

Comment: I'm sorry I was a bit vague, I'm having trouble exactly wording the question. I want a way to encode an array such that its encoding is equal to the encodings of all its rotations, and different from all other possible array's encodings. An array's rotations include the array if you rotate it once, twice, and so on. The encoding of a sorted array and permutation number would be a way of encoding a single array, but this wouldn't have the property of all possible rotations equaling each other, as the permutations numbers would be different for each rotation.

Comment: Following your example, [2, 1, 3] could be encoded as ([1, 2, 3], x) where x is the permutation number. I want this to be equal to the encoding of [1, 3, 2], which is the original array just rotated once, but the encoding of this new array would be ([1, 2, 3], y), y being different than x, so this encoding doesn't work. I need an encoding that makes these rotated versions all equal.

Comment: If we were to ignore the permutation number though, this would cause a new problem, as invalid arrays could become equal. Using the same array as before, [2, 1, 3]'s encoding would equal [1, 3, 2]'s encoding, which would be good. But, it would also equal [3, 1, 2]'s encoding, which would be bad, as [2, 1, 3] and [3, 1, 2] are not rotations of one another: you could not rotate one a number of times to create the other.